# Jest encountered an unexpected token '='

Tags: javascript, jestjs, token

I created a test using a javascript enum as per this tutorial:
https://www.sohamkamani.com/javascript/enums/

I tested it in standard javascript but i keep getting an error when using it in Jest:
Jest encountered an unexpected token '='

```
 static test1 = new test("test1");
               ^

 SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
```

this is the enum i created:

```
     class test { 

       constructor(name) { 
          this.name = name;
        }

      static test1 = new test("test1")
      static test2 = new test("test2")
      static test3 = new test("test3")
    }
```

Comment: Is it wanted that your test class holds references to itself (3 test objects ) ?

Comment: Jest might be running in an environment which doesn't support public class fields

Comment: Hi, @evolutionxbox, how do i check if its running in an environment which doesn't support public class fields? and is it something i can change? Thanks bro

Comment: You shouldn't need to. Instead look into using babel with jest https://jest-bot.github.io/jest/docs/babel.html

Comment: thanks @evolutionxbox for that, ill see if it fixes my issue